# Elements of a monoid generated by a single element.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a real quadratic field and $\epsilon$ be its fundamental unit. When we consider the monoid $\mathfrak{M}$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$ where $\mathfrak{M}$ is generated by $\epsilon$, does this mean that $\mathfrak{M}=\{ \epsilon ^n : n \in \mathbb{N}_0\}$? I just want some clarification on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is exactly what it means.